# Code prints NaN on server cluster, but works on my OS X machine

Tags: c, macos, printf, mpi, nan

**EDIT** : found my answer, see below (can't accept my own answer yet)

On Mac OS X I developed a code which computes floating-point values in matrix, and changes the value over time (simulating heat transfer on a metallic plate).

When I run it on my MacBook `Darwin my-mbp 14.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Thu Feb 26 19:26:47 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.10.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`, everything works fine.

However the point is to run it on a 
`Linux cluster0 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` to access the cluster of multiple CPU's (from 2 to 24 for parallel computing)

On my laptop, everything works (I get the valid result printed in console)
But when I transfer the code via SFTP on the server, compile it and run it, I noticed the values slowly become printed as -NaN (the first iterations only a few numbers become NaN, but after like 5-6 iterations all values become -NaN)

Here are the crucial parts of my code :

```
void initMatrix(size_t M, size_t N, double (*matrix)[M][N][2])
{
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            (*matrix)[i][j][0] = (double)(( i * ( M - i - 1 ) ) * ( j * ( N - j - 1 ) ));
        }
    }
    printf("Matrix has been initialized\n");
}

void printMatrix(size_t M, size_t N, double (*matrix)[M][N][2], int k) 
{
    int i, j;
    // Counting backwards since the 0,0 coordinate is at the bottom not the top
    for (j = N-1; j >= 0; --j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            printf("\t");
            printf("%0.1f", (*matrix)[i][j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


const size_t N = (size_t)n;
const size_t M = (size_t)m;
double mat[M][N][2];
initMatrix(M, N, &mat);
printMatrix(M, N, &mat, 0);

double tdh2 = td/(h*h);
int i, j, k, currentK, previousK;
for (k = 1; k <= np; ++k)
{
    currentK = k%2;
    previousK = (k-1)%2;

    for (j = 1; j < N-1; ++j)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < M-1; ++i)
        {   
            // Simulation calcul intensif
            usleep(5);
            mat[i][j][currentK] = (double)((1 - (4*tdh2))*mat[i][j][previousK] + (tdh2*(
                                    mat[i-1][j][previousK] 
                                    + mat[i+1][j][previousK]
                                    + mat[i][j-1][previousK]
                                    + mat[i][j+1][previousK] )));
        }   
    }
    system("clear");
    printf("\n");
    printMatrix(M, N, &mat, currentK);
}
```

**My question is : what makes my code produce '-NaN' on the Linux cluster but work perfectly on my MacOS machine?**

Comment: What are the definitions of td and h?

Comment: They are passed as args and have a valid value, I just forgot to put that part of the code here. But I found out the problem which was in my init function (I just don't know why it worked on my laptop but not the server)

Comment: Incidentally, what do you think that the `0` achieves in `%0.1f`?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem which was that 1 dimension of the initialized matrix was in fact not initialized (I thought this wouldn't be a problem since it would later be given a value)

```
void initMatrix(size_t M, size_t N, double (*matrix)[M][N][2])
{
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            (*matrix)[i][j][0] = (double)(( i * ( M - i - 1 ) ) * ( j * ( N - j - 1 ) ));
            // I NEEDED TO INITIALIZE (*matrix)[i][j][1] TOO
            (*matrix)[i][j][1] = (*matrix)[i][j][0];
        }
    }
    printf("Matrix has been initialized\n");
}
```

The problem probably comes from the fact that it is initialized to zero **implicitly** on my OS X system but stays uninitialized by default on the Linux system. That would explain why it works perfectly on my laptop but not on the server.

Comment: If N and M were constant, this would not be a problem.

Comment: Got it: the algorithm does not overwrite all values in currentK, the boundary values still have to be initialized. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yep that was exactly the problem @LeonardMichlmayr !

Comment: fwiw, Macs tend to zero out memory as a security measure, so your process can't read old/stale data from other processes. This is not guaranteed behavior, but it does show up at times.

Comment: @EricS you nailed why it never showed any problem on my Mac but did fail on the server! But in the end it was just all my mistake, not the computer's, as usual :)